# Reading data of multiple level of multiple checkboxes in Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, checkbox

I have a page that is something like below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
    <form action="/edit_submit/" method="POST">
    {% for item in result %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" id={{ item.id }} value="1">Apple
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" id={{ item.id }} value="2">Water
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" id={{ item.id }} value="3">Cake
            {% csrf_token %}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">    
</form>
```

I need a way to read all the checkboxes value with name `options` on the page during submit, without knowing the `item.id` values. Hence I need an output which gives me tuples as `item.id,value,checked`.

I know that `id` is not unique here, however is there a better solution for grouping checkboxes? I can put `item.id` as `name` in html, but remember I do not know the `item.id` which appeared on the page.

Comment: Use `data-id` instead of `id`. Also you can use `id="{{ item.id }}_1"` so each ID will be unique.

Comment: making id unique is not the goal here, I want a way to read all checkbox attributes in all the checkbox on that webpage, i.e. all the id, value, checked

Comment: Without it being unique, you probably won't be able to do that. Javascript can behave strange when there is no uniqueness in IDs.

Comment: ok i made them unique, and i want to access them in python (django to be specific)